# Disabling HTTPS for a single service/domain using Docker labels

Tags: docker, traefik

I've been running a Traefik + Let's Encrypt setup in a Docker Swarm environment for quite a while, and everything has been working smoothly, with only HTTPS enabled, as I'm forcibly redirecting HTTP -> HTTPS.

The issue I now have is that I have a specific site/service that *requires* HTTP-only, but so far I haven't been able to figure out how to *only* disable the HTTP->HTTPS redirection for this particular service, as I'd really rather not disable it for all of my sites/services.

My current `traefik.toml` is fairly simple:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["https", "http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.http.redirect]
  entryPoint = "https"

  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

  ...
```

In the container itself, I've tried setting labels such as `traefik.fontend.entryPoints=http`, but that didn't make a difference, likely due to the redirection currently in place.

So my question is: how can I disable either the redirection *or* HTTPS for a specific container, preferrably using only labels?

Comment: "I have a specific site/service that requires HTTP-only", you mean the client must connect with http or the container must be reached with http?

Comment: @Siyu Both. Having support for both HTTP and HTTPS is fine, and actually preferred, but if I disabled the global HTTP->HTTPS redirection, then HTTP becomes the default for _all_ sites, which is not what I want, even though it works for this particular site.

Comment: don't think you can: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3122